# Why is my program looping too many times?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm a beginner in C and trying to create a program and having a problem with my main function.

**Problem:**

1. After asking how many integers they'd like to enter, for example: 4 numbers, the loop goes on 5 times essentially taking in 5 numbers. It also only prints "Next: " after the 2nd number.
2. In my `while` loop, which I put for error checking, after the user puts a valid method, example: enters 1, it will print out that it's an "invalid choice" and re-asks again only once more.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "a3defs.h"

int main() {
  StackType stk;
  StackType *stkPtr = &stk;

  //Will be used to check whether to use recursive or iterative
  int method = 0;
  int sum;
  int *sumPnt = &sum;

  //Will be used to create array for amount of ints:
  int numOfIntegers;

  //Array of ints:
  int *userInts;
  printf("How many integers would you like to enter? "); 
  scanf("%d", &numOfIntegers);
  userInts = (int*)calloc(numOfIntegers, sizeof(int)); //Create the array

  printf("Please enter %d numbers: \n", numOfIntegers);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < numOfIntegers; i++) {
    scanf("%d\n", &userInts[i]);
    printf("Next:");
  }

  while(1) {
    printf("Would you like to used iterative or recursive to sum?\n");
    printf("Enter 1 for iterative or 2 for recursive: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &method); 
    if (method == 1) {
      //found in loop.c
      sumIterative(stkPtr, numOfIntegers, userInts, sumPnt);
      break;
    } else if (method == 2) {
      //Found in loop.c
      sumRecursive(stkPtr, numOfIntegers, userInts, sumPnt);
      break;
    } else {
      printf("Invalid choice. Repeating... \n");
        continue;
    }
  } 

  printf("Your sum is: %d", *sumPnt);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `scanf("%d\n", &userInts[i]);` with `scanf("%d", &userInts[i]);`

See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) about entering a nonwhitespace character in format specifier in scanf.

It says:

> Any character
>   that is not either a whitespace character (blank, newline or tab) or
>   part of a format specifier (which begin with a % character) causes the
>   function to read the next character from the stream, compare it to
>   this non-whitespace character and if it matches, it is discarded and
>   the function continues with the next character of format. If the
>   character does not match, the function fails, returning and leaving
>   subsequent characters of the stream unread.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1:

Just replace :

```
scanf("%d\n", &userInts[i]);
```

by `scanf("%d", &userInts[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

And add `fflush(stdout)` after all `printf` statements where the format string doesn't end with `\n`. Otherwise the output will be displayed only after the next `\n` is output.